# Is it possible to make a command to search for embeds?

Tags: discord.js

Im trying to make a command to search for embeds that i have created ex /search blahblah would it be possible?

I just wanted to see if it is possible

Comment: Could you specify what you are searching for? Are you looking for embeds that your own discord bot as previously created or just any embed that has been created? What are you searching for the embeds by (text content, title content)?

Comment: Like embeds that my bot makes

Comment: Also im using .ts not .js

Comment: an option would be to store these embeds in JSON using the messageID

Comment: Yes, it can be done, just not sure how in typescript. In general, you 'fetch' all the messages and then just filter them based on messages.embeds.length.